# iPad mini wont update over iOS 10

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-id, software-update

I have been trying to update my iPad mini. But I don’t know what version it is. And I tried on the Mac computer, but it says current update is iOS 9.3.5. And it won’t let me make a new Apple account.

Answer (score 2):

You apparently have the original (first generation) iPad Mini. The last version of iOS released for the generation of iPad Mini is iOS 9.3.5 (iOS 9.3.6 for Wi-Fi + Cellular models). So it's not possible to update it to iOS 10 or later.

> it won’t let me make a new Apple account.

You can register for a new Apple account by going the the Apple ID website on any computer. Visit the following link:

- https://appleid.apple.com/account#!&page=create